# Ajax variable not passing to php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am looking to pass the value of cityField in ajax to $_POST['cityField']. Everything looks in order but the variable is not passing to php on nextpage.php

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$('#city').blur(function() {
    var cityField=$('#city').val();
    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url:"nextpage.php",
        data:{'cityField':cityField },
        dataType:"html",
        success:function(data) {
            alert("You typed:"+cityField);
        }
    });
});
 </script>
```

Comment: And what's happened? Can you post your php site method?

Comment: show whats there in nextpage.php also how do you verify that the value is not passing?

Comment: You are alerting "cityField", on success event. Alert "data" to see server response.

Comment: by the way you can go to the network tab in firebug and check to understand what exactly happened with your ajax request. Also check the console for errors

Comment: What is `#city` on your page?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use 'cityField' as object. Because data contains paramaters in the format data{ object: value}.
Use this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#city').blur(function() {
var cityField=$('#city').val();
$.ajax({
    type:"post",
    url:"nextpage.php",
    data:{myobj:cityField },
    dataType:"html",
    success:function(data) {
        alert("You typed:"+cityField);
    });
</script>
```

and then retrieve myobj in server side.

Answer (score 0):

In your success function you'll get the data send by `nextpage.php` in the var named `data`. You are alerting the `cityfield` variable.

So change your success function to resemble something like this:

```
....
success: function (data) {
    console.log('This is the answer of nextpage.php : '+ data;
}
...
```

Besides that, maybe it's a good idea to strip the data to an object outside of your `$.ajax` call:

```
var myPostData = {};
myPostData.cityField = $('#city').val();

....
data: myPostData,
....
```

Answer (score 0):

it's simple.change to :

```
...
data:$('#city').serialize()
...
```

or use this fully :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#city').blur(function() {
    var $this=this;
    $.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url:"nextpage.php",
        data:$($this).serialize(),
        dataType:"html",
        success:function(data) {
            alert("You typed:"+cityField);
        }
    });
});
 </script>
```

for more see this : http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: note :in my answers, #city should be input element.What is #city on your work?